# how to disable level 2 cache in spring batch?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-batch

I want to disable the hibernate level 2 cache in spring batch. Because I am batch updating the entities with RepositoryItemWriter, I think the cache is not useful in this case, right? And How to disable it?

The code for repository writer is below:

```
    @Bean
    public RepositoryItemWriter<User> writer() {
        return new RepositoryItemWriterBuilder<User>().methodName("saveAndFlush").repository(userRepository).build();
    }
```

I tried this:

```
Session session = entityManager.unwrap(Session.class)
session.setCacheMode(CacheMode.IGNORE);
```

but not worked, any help are appreciated~

Comment: The second-level cache and query cache are disabled by default (and queries are not cached unless you explicitly cache them. still try with spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache=false in application.properties

Answer (score 0):

If you use the `RepositoryItemWriter`, then this configuration option should be done at the Spring Data repository level (your `userRepository`) and not through the Spring Batch item writer (since this writer delegates writing to the repository).

However, since you are using Hibernate, I can suggest using the `HibernateItemWriter` with the [`StatelessSession`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/StatelessSession.html) which, from its Javadoc, does not interact with any second-level cache.